# Sequelize - Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, webpack, sequelize.js

Im just learn to use sequelize for my node.js project. For summary my project is ExpressJS+Typescript with Sequelize as ORM and Webpack as module bundler.

Below is my project structure.

```
src
-router
-server
--config
   config.json
--controllers
   index.ts
   User.ts
--migrations
--models
   index.js
   user.js
--seeders
 App.ts
 index.ts
```

(sorry can not post picture yet, new user to stackoverflow)

I have build some simple router '/user' and expect it should call the user controller and call sequelize method findAll() from my models module, but the result is its error says **Cannot read property 'list' of undefined**. Below is my code:
*models/index.js*

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.json`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, config
  );
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;
```

*models/user.js*

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    wallet: DataTypes.DECIMAL
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        user.hasMany(models.top_up);
      }
    }
  });
  return user;
};
```

*controllers/User.ts*

```
let user = require('../models').user;

export default {
    list(req, res) {
        return user
        .findAll()
        .then(topUp => res.status(200).send(topUp))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    }
};
```

*controllers/Index.ts*

```
import users from './User'

export default {
    users
}
```

*router/router.ts*

```
import * as express from 'express';

const userController = require('../server/controllers').users;

// Init express router
let router = express.Router();

// Setting API URL
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Hello World!'
    });
});

router.get('/about',(req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<p>This is about about</p>');
});

router.get('/user', userController.list());

export default router
```

Fyi, all of my project configuration for start express server, typescript compile and webpack bundle is fine already, and the other route for '/' and '/about' is work fine. I know there is something I'm missing, im still new to sequelize, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: The `server/controllers/index.ts` does not export a binding named `users`, itexports a binding named `default`.

You are importing the `controllers/Index.ts` module using the `require` function. In a CommonJS environment, this imports the entire `module.exports` object. As currently transpiled by TypeScript, every named export of the required module is exposed as a property of the import.

An `export default` clause implies an export named `default`. As per the ES Module specification, there is a shorthand for importing the `default` export of a module. That shorthand is

```
import userController from '../server/controllers';
```

On the other hand, the syntax

```
import userController = require('../server/controllers');
```

or

```
const userController = require('../server/controllers'); // (or let or var)
```

imports an object with a property corresponding to each export. In this case it has the shape

```
{ default }
```

So if you use `require`, you need to write

```
import  userController = require('../server/controllers').default;
```

or

```
import userController from '../server/controllers';
```

All ES Module style exports are named, including the default which is named `default`.

To illustrate this, consider the following, more verbose but semantically identical form

```
import {default as userController} from '../server/controllers';
```

If you would prefer to stick with CommonJS style exports, eschewing ES Modules when working in NodeJS, the idiomatic way to export a single object *as* the entire module (the object returned by require)

You may write

```
// ../server/controllers/index.ts
export = {
  list(req, res) {
    return user
    .findAll()
    .then(topUp => res.status(200).send(topUp))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
};
```

Personally, I would stick with what you have and write

```
import userController from '../server/controllers';
```